# Tilda, Button, Form, JS

Tags: javascript, tilda

У меня в тильде есть Zero Block с кнопками (например b1, b2, b3) и есть блок с формой в которой есть выпадающий список со значениями (l1, l2, l3). Как мне сделать так, чтобы по нажатию b1, b2, b3 из Zero Block, страница опускалась к блоку с формой и там в списке выставлялось автоматически, соответственно, l1, l2, l3?

Answer (score 1):

Решил сам разобраться в данном вопросе, так как ответа не поступило:
Выбрал селектор с кнопкой b1 и навесил событие onclick а у же на него функцию которая выставляет определенный параметр из массива самого selectbox'а, который тоже выбираем селектором:

```
$(document).querySelector('b1_Selector').onclick = function() {
    $(document).querySelector ('selectbox_Selector').options [0].selected = true;
}
```

Соответственно если нужен пункт меню l2, то индекс options меняем на 1 и так далее. Остальные кнопки делаются по аналогии подставляя соответствующий селектор и параметр options.